# Rotate canvas 90 degrees clockwise and update width height

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

Say we have a canvas:

```
<canvas id="one" width="100" height="200"></canvas>
```

And on a button click the canvas gets rotated 90 degrees clockwise (around the center) and the dimensions of the canvas get also updated, so in a sense it looks like this afterwards:

```
<canvas id="one" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Note that the id of the canvas is the same.

Imagine simply rotating an image clockwise without it being cropped or being padded.

Any suggestions before I do it the long way of creating a new canvas and rotating and copying pixel by pixel?

**UPDATE** sample code with suggestion from comments still not working:

```
function imageRotatecw90(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("one");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    var myImageData = context.getImageData(0,0, cw,ch);

    context.save();

    context.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
    context.rotate(Math.PI/2);

    context.putImageData(myImageData, 0, 0);

    context.restore();

    canvas.width=ch;
    canvas.height=cw;
}
```

[FiddleJS](http://jsfiddle.net/ziqbal/wmyUS/1/)

Comment: Why copy pixel by pixel? Why not grab the image as an imagedata, resize the canvas, rotate the context and then set the canvas' image as the previous image data? It's about a dozen lines of pretty easy code.

Comment: @Stephen I'll try that. Hoping theres no gotchas.

Comment: @Stephen I've tried using ImageData but its not doing anything part from changing canvas dimensions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/t4YX4/).

To achieve the results seen in demo, I made use of `canvas.toDataURL` to cache the canvas into an image, then reset the canvas to their new dimensions, translate and rotate the context properly and finally draw the cached image back to modified canvas.

That way you easily rotate the canvas without need to redraw everything again. But because `anti-aliasing` methods used by browser, each time this operation is done you'll notice some blurriness in result. If you don't like this behavior the only solution I could figure out is to draw everything again, what is much more difficult to track.

Here follows the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("one");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;

// Sample graphic
context.beginPath();
context.rect(10, 10, 20, 50);
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 7;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();

// create button
var button = document.getElementById("rotate");
button.onclick = function () {
    // rotate the canvas 90 degrees each time the button is pressed
    rotate();
}

var myImageData, rotating = false;   

var rotate = function () {
    if (!rotating) {
        rotating = true;            
        // store current data to an image
        myImageData = new Image();
        myImageData.src = canvas.toDataURL();

       myImageData.onload = function () {
            // reset the canvas with new dimensions
            canvas.width = ch;
            canvas.height = cw;
            cw = canvas.width;
            ch = canvas.height;

            context.save();
            // translate and rotate
            context.translate(cw, ch / cw);
            context.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
            // draw the previows image, now rotated
            context.drawImage(myImageData, 0, 0);               
            context.restore();

            // clear the temporary image
            myImageData = null;

            rotating = false;               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've managed to get working code which is very similar to your idea. Instead of using an intermediate image I'm using a secondary canvas to hold the pixels. This avoids the onload complexity and my code is only 5 lines long.

Comment: Nice. I've made some code that way too. One other great advantage of use the secondary canvas is to avoid the constantly creation of image objects reducing garbage collector actions.

Answer (score 1):

**Rotation**

Note it is not possible to rotate a single element.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(0.17);

// Clear the current drawings.
ctx.fillRect()

// draw your object
ctx.restore();
```

**Width/height adjustment**

The only way I ever found to properly deal with display ratios, screen sizes etc:

```
canvas.width = 20;// DO NOT USE PIXELS
canvas.height = 40; // AGAIN NO PIXELS
```

Notice I am intentionally **not** using `canvas.style.width` or `canvas.style.height`. Also for an adjustable canvas don't rely on CSS or media queries to do the transformations, they are a headache because of the pixel ratio differences. JavaScript automatically accounts for those.

**Update**

You also have to update the width and the height before you draw. Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I guess this isn't a problem:

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/wmyUS/3/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("one");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;

canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 400;

// Sample graphic
context.beginPath();
context.rect(10,10,20,50);
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 7;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();


var myImageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, cw, ch);

context.save();

context.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
context.putImageData(myImageData, 0, 0);
context.rotate(0.20);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added some sample code which isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate an image by 90 degrees this might be helpful:

```
export const rotateBase64Image = async (base64data: string) => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = base64data;

  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    image.onload = function () {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      if (!ctx) throw new Error("cannnot get context '2d'");
      canvas.width = image.height;
      canvas.height = image.width;
      ctx.setTransform(0, 1, -1, 0, canvas.width, 0); // overwrite existing transform
      ctx!.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

      canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        if (!blob) {
          return reject("Canvas is empty");
        }
        const fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        resolve(fileUrl);
      }, "image/jpeg");
    };
  });
};
```

If you don't have image in base64 format you can do it like this:

```
const handleRotate = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(link);
  const blob = await res.blob();
  const b64: string = await blobToB64(blob);
  const rotatedImage = await rotateBase64Image(b64)
  setLink(rotatedImage);
}
```

Here is my blobTob64 function:

```
export const blobToB64 = async (blob) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
};
```